# how do I get my google play store to start working for my Samsung galaxy exhibit (T559)?

Tags: google-play-store

I was going through my app settings and accidentally uninstalled all my updates on my Google play store, it lets me pull up the old version but it will close out and say it has stopped working . I have tried to fix it but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the apk version from this link:
[Google Play store 5.5.12](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-5-5-12-android-apk-download/)

And install it after you downloaded it.
You might change the security settings of your phone to download apps from other sources.